# Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null com ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tenho um ngFor que adiciona varias strings, e esses dados vem de uma api

```
<p class="teste" *ngFor="let element of objeto_retorno" >Filial {{ element.FILIAL }} = {{ element.TOTAL }} </p>
```

e no ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    document.querySelector('.teste').setAttribute('class','cor')
  }
```

Mas ele fica dando esse erro: ***Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null***

Eu acredito que seja por causa do ngFor, mas não estou conseguindo resolver isso, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.teste')` está retornando null....

Comment: Sim, eu percebi isso, mas como resolvo isso? pq ele ta pegando a class, e coloquei até pra pegar o ID e nao vai

Comment: Eu testei aqui com a classe e tb não foi, mas pelo id deu.

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que no momento que o ngOnInit é executado a view não está completamente carregada e possívelmente o elemento ainda não existe. De uma olhada no life cycle hooks https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#ondestroy. Tenta substituir ngOnInit por ngAfterViewInit

Comment: eu testei aqui, mas mesmo assim continua null

Comment: Aqui funcionou: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fvhftk

Comment: ainda assim aqui nao funciona, e nao faço ideia do pq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recomendo que use o próprio Angular,** não precisa fazer coisas do tipo manualmente.

Usar `querySelector` e `querySelectorAll` para elementos que mudam constantemente com Angular é bastante desnecessário e ainda por cima **problemático**.

E então aplicar diretamente (se for de fato no momento que os elementos são populados/gerados):

```
<p class="teste" *ngFor="let element of objeto_retorno" >Filial {{ element.FILIAL }} = {{ element.TOTAL }} </p>
```

Só pra constar o problema é que mesmo que `ngAfterViewInit` resolva de primeira, se os dados forem repopulados o DOM é alterado, geralmente os elementos nem existem ainda, mesmo que a tela tenha sido carregada, mesmo que seja imperceptível para você talvez os elementos demorem alguns milissegundos para serem gerados, e por isto algo como não vai funcionar direito:

```
 document.querySelector('.teste').setAttribute('class','cor')
```

Mas se o que deseja é aplicar conforme um evento ocorra então faça algo como:

```
<p [class]="propriedadeDaClasse ? 'cor': 'teste'" *ngFor="let element of objeto_retorno" >Filial {{ element.FILIAL }} = {{ element.TOTAL }} </p>
```

Este exemplo acima seria o equivalente do `setAttribute` (que troca a classe), note que `propriedadeDaClasse` pode ser uma "if" também, algo como:

```
<p [class]="x != y ? 'cor': 'teste'" *ngFor="let element of objeto_retorno" >Filial {{ element.FILIAL }} = {{ element.TOTAL }} </p>
```

Tanto a variavel hipotética `propriedadeDaClasse`, quanto `x` e `y` devem existir no escopo do `this` da sua classe, algo como, exemplos:

```
export class FooBar {
    propriedadeDaClasse = false;
}
```

Ou:

```
export class FooBar {
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
}
```

Agora se deseja manter a classe "teste" junto com "cor" terá que fazer assim:

```
<p [class]="propriedadeDaClasse ? 'teste cor': 'teste'" *ngFor="let element of objeto_retorno" >Filial {{ element.FILIAL }} = {{ element.TOTAL }} </p>
```

Então desta forma o próprio Angular vai entender quando o DOM é alterado e aplicar as classes conforme necessário.

---

Se forem classes (cores variadas) o melhor seria aplicar a cor a uma variavel, algo como:

```
export class FooBar {
    mainColor = ''; //começa sem cor, mas pode trocar '' por algo como 'cor'

     ...
}
```

Então no:

```
<p [class]="mainColor + ' teste'" *ngFor="let element of objeto_retorno" >Filial {{ element.FILIAL }} = {{ element.TOTAL }} </p>
```

Assim concatena `mainColor + ' teste'` ambas classes, o que vai gerar coisas como:

```
class="cor1 teste"
```

ou:

```
class="cor2 teste"
```

Ai dentro da classe basta trocar a cor a qualquer momento, por exemplo:

```
this.mainColor = 'cor1';
```

Ou:

```
this.mainColor = 'cor2';
```

E no css:

```
.cor1 {
    color: red;
}

.cor2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

São só exemplos, você adapta a sua necessidade

Comment: tem como aplicar mais de um if aí dentro? pq preciso que ele mude para outra cor caso o valor seja maior que 8 e depois para outro se ele for maior que 10

Comment: @Maria isso é um exemplo de if `[class]="x != y ? 'cor': 'teste'"`, agora quiser mais cores o melhor seria setar o valor em uma variavel na classe e aplicar diretamente, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: @Maria pronto, resposta editada.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer o `querySelector` por um id.

```js
document.querySelector('#idteste').setAttribute('class','cor');

console.log('document.querySelector(\'#idteste\')', document.querySelector('#idteste'))
console.log('document.querySelector(\'.teste\')', document.querySelector('.teste'))
```

```html
<p id="idteste" class="teste" *ngFor="let element of objeto_retorno" >
```

**Edit:**
[Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/13LHRD4yPfdas8yT?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

Tem que ser colocado no `ngAfterViewInit` pois nesta etapa o DOM estará completamente carregado.

Comment: testei e fica dando null

Comment: Em vez de ser no `ngOnInit` coloca no `ngAfterViewInit`, acho que é pq o DOM carrega depois com id e class.

Comment: mesma coisa, ta dando null

Comment: `objeto_retorno` tá vazio?

Comment: ta nao, ta retornando varios string

Comment: Bom... fiz o exemplo no plunker... Quando está no `ngOnInit` dá o erro, mas no `ngAfterViewInit` não dá... Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/13LHRD4yPfdas8yT?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

Comment: eu vejo, mas por qual razao aqui nao tá funcionando? os dados que estao aparecendo vem de uma api